# Stop searching the file server

Tags: search, crawling

We have two root folders where most of our organization's files are stored:

Folder1 = static documents
Folder2 = department specific restricted documents

We would like to stop crawling Folder2 in our SharePoint searches. Can someone show me how to do this? I couldn't find anything Central Administration, on Google, or this site.

Thanks!
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in front of SharePoint right now, so this is off the top of my head:

Clarification first: are these folders in SharePoint or are they content sources on your file system?

Within SharePoint you can set any library to be excluded from search. I'm not sure where "root folder" fits into the picture. If it's a library, use the library settings > advanced ... to exclude it from search. If it's a net share you will have to actively create a content source to *include* it in the search. If you don't want it in the search anymore, just delete the content source.

Or define your default search scope not to include that content source.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear in my original post. The two folders I'm referring to reside on our network file server. We would like to setup SharePoint to stop searching Folder2 and continue searching Folder1 as well as SharePoint content.

Comment: So edit the content source in the Search service application in Central Administration and remove the net share folder2.